# rest full service in express web application

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I have to implement a **express web application** to use rest services with mongodb.

my **DBConfig.js** file is like below which include my db schema,

```
var Mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Schema = Mongoose.Schema;

const UserSchema = new Schema({
name : {
    type: String,
    require: true
},
address : {
    type: String,
    require: false
},
password: {
    type: String,
    require: true
}
});

Mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
Mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/demo", function (err) {
if (err) {
    console.log(err);
    process.exit(-1);
}
console.log("Connected");
});

module.exports = Mongoose;
```

all the relevant methods are implement in my **Controller.js** file

```
var Mongoose = require("../DBSchema/DBConfig");
var UserSchema = Mongoose.model('User');


var Controller = function() {
this.insertUser = function (data) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        var User = new UserSchema({
            name: data.name,
            address: data.address,
            password: data.password
        });

        User.save().then(function () {
            resolve({status: 200, message: "User inserted successfully"})
        }).catch(function (err) {
            reject({status: 500, message: "Error:- " + err})
        });
    });
}

this.getAll = function () {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        UserSchema.find().exec().then(function (data) {
            resolve({status: 200, Userdata: data})
        }).catch(function (err) {
            resolve({status: 500, message : "No data available"})
        })
    })
}

this.getuser = function (id) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        UserSchema.find({_id: id}).exec().then(function (data) {
            resolve({status: 200, userSearched: data});
        }).catch(function (err) {
            reject({status: 404, message: "User NOT FOUND"});
        })
    })
}
this.updateUser = function (id, data) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        UserSchema.update({_id: id}, data).then(function (data) {
            resolve({status: 200, message: "User updated successfully"})
        }).catch(function (err) {
            reject({status: 500, message: "Error:- " + err})

        })
    })
}

this.remove = function (id) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        UserSchema.remove({_id: id}).then(function () {
            resolve({status: 200, message: "Successfully deleted"})
        }).catch(function (err) {
            resolve({status: 500, message: "Error : "+err})
        })
    })
}
}

module.exports = new Controller();
```

now I have to call my rest services,I want to know how can I use these methods which are in my controller to access data.

I'm using postman to view my data.
the output should be

```
{
"data": [
    {
        "_id": "5cf724a58c9b061ba062a28c",
        "name": "name1",
        "address": "adress1",
        "password": "password1",
        "__v": 0
    }
]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need is you have to define the routes in your URL to access relevant method, example I create a file called **User.Routes.js** under a folder called UserController which you can add your Controller.js file also to arrange in an order to get a clear idea. and also assume you add your DBConfig.js file under folder called DBSchema, which made you to do good code practise.

```
var Express = require('express');
var router = Express.Router();
var Controller = require('./Controller')

router.get('/',function (req,res) {
Controller.getAll().then(function (data) {
    res.status(data.status).send({data:data.Userdata})
});
});

router.get('/:id',function (req,res) {
Controller.getuser(req.params.id).then(function (data) {
    res.status(data.status).send({data:data.userSearched});
});
});

router.post('/',function(req,res){
Controller.insertUser(req.body).then(function (data) {
    res.status(data.status).send({message: data.message});
}).catch(function (err) {
    res.status(err.status).send({message: err.message});
});
});

router.put('/:id',function (req,res) {
Controller.updateUser(req.params.id,req.body).then(function (data) {
    res.status(data.status).send({message: data.message});
});
});

router.delete('/:id', function (req,res) {
Controller.remove(req.params.id).then(function (data) {
    res.status(data.status).send({message: data.message});
});
});

module.exports = router;
```

and now you need to use methods in your User.Routes.js via postman. for that you need to give url name to be accessed. example, I create **Routes.js** file

```
const Express = require("express");

var Routes = Express.Router();
var UserRoute = require('./UserController/User.Route');

Routes.use('/user/', UserRoute);
module.exports = Routes;
```

like this if you want to view data from your schema you have to add the url like -"http://localhost:8083/user"

and your **app.js** file want to require the created Routes file for that you can do like,

```
const Express = require("express");
const app = Express();
const BodyParser = require("body-parser");
const Routes = require("./Routes");

app.use(BodyParser.json());
app.use("/", Routes);

app.listen(8083, "localhost", function(err) {
if (err) {
console.log(err);
process.exit(-1);
}
console.log("Server listening on port 8083");
});
```

Now using postman you can add user,update and delete particular user by giving user id in your URL like - "http://localhost:8083/user/5cf724a58c9b061ba062a28c"

Comment: Thanks @jthiva it works fine. Now I get a clear idea.